# Shared memory not granted permission to parent process

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have a problem in my C code about shared memory.

I have a C code that doesn't work as I expected:

```
#include "sys/ipc.h"
#include "sys/shm.h"

#include "unistd.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/wait.h"

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile.txt", 65);
    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT);
    if (fork() != 0){
        int * ptr = (int *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0); // This line returns -1
                            // This only happened
                            //  to parrent
        printf("shmid parrent = %d\n", shmid);
        perror("Error ");
        *ptr = 6;
        shmdt(ptr);
        wait(NULL);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }
    else{
        printf("shmid child = %d\n", shmid);
        int * ptr = (int *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0); // Works as expected
        printf("ptr address = %p\n", ptr);      
        shmdt(ptr);
        printf("Now child can exit normally");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result follows (gdb):

```
shmid parrent = 45
Error : Permission denied
shmid child = 45
ptr address = 0xffffffffffffffff
Now child can exit normally
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555552d0 in main () at main_2.c:20
20          *ptr = 6;
```

I expected both the parent process and the child process to work fine. Only the child process exited normally. I am not sure what is the problem with the parent process. Thank you very much!

Update 1: The ptr in both parent and child process is always `(void *) -1`. I am not sure how to make the `shmat()` not to return that value.

Update 2: The file "shmfile.txt" is at the same location of the `main` excutable file.

Comment: You  should only check `errno` if the pointer returned from`shmat` is `(void*)-1`. Otherwise it is just some meaningless value.

Comment: `ftok()` documentation says that "*pathname* must refer to an existing, accessible file".   Is "shmfile.txt" an existing file?

Comment: In summary, you should check errors in all the OS calls (`ftok()`, `shmget()`, `shmat()`) and not wait until you have an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify permission used to create the shared memory.
For instance using

```
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

From the documentation of [shmget](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html):

> In addition to the above flags, the least significant 9 bits of
> shmflg specify the permissions granted to the owner, group, and
> others.  These bits have the same format, and the same meaning,
> as the mode argument of open(2).  Presently, execute permissions
> are not used by the system.

With this modification your code is running.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/FQzNUA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This solved my problem.

Comment: `0666` is probably excessive, however, as it grants full read/write access to every process.

Comment: @AndrewHenle you are right, it is just for an example 0640 may be better